# including header files in .cpp files

Tags: c++, g++, header-files

I have a file SpreadSheetCell.h and SpreadSheetCell.cpp.
I have another file SpreadSheet.cpp which includes SpreadSheetCell.h .In this case it is giving me errors like "undefined reference to SpreadSheetCell:SpreadSheetCell()" etc.
 But when i try to include SpreadSheetCell.cpp instead the errors are gone. Is it not common to include the header files rather than the cpp files? What can i possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Or what could you be doing right, it's all point of view because there is no source Luke.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is asking a question without giving enough details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a linking error and means that you are not including a sourcefile that has the definition for `SpreadSheetCell:SpreadSheetCell()` when compiling.

You are probably missing `SpreadSheetCell.cpp` in the command line you use, e.g. something like:

```
g++ -o myBinary SpreadSheet.cpp SpreadSheetCell.cpp [...more files?]
```

Comment: Aww.. Yes i forgot to include SpreadSheetCell.cpp while compiling. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to include source code. Always only include header files.

I can't look in your file(s), however, I think that SPreadSheetCell.h includes a file (SpreadSheet.h maybe?) so that a circular dependency exist.

The best way is to make a graph of the files that are included (in both cpp and h files). If there is a 'circle' somewhere you have found the problem. In that case you should remove one link so the circle is broken or split files up in smaller files (also to remove the circle).

(with 'circle' I mean e.g. a file A including B including C including A again.)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your SpreadSheetCell.cpp has a *#include "SpreadSheetCell.h"*, if not show your code and your compiling commands!